# Getting resolved queue name for an alias queue in mq api exit

Tags: api, queue, alias, ibm-mq, exit

I am trying to get the resolved queue name (i.e. the base queue name of an alias queue) in open_after and put1_before API exit by looking at ResolvedQName field of Object descriptor(MQOD). But it does not seem to contain the base queue name (i.e. is either blank or is some unexpected value like.. '1.59.15') within these exits.  I can however see that the ObjectName has been properly set with the alias queue name. For clarity my alias queue and the base queue both are with the same local QM.

So I am wondering if there is anyway to get the resolved queue name within MQ API exit when making (open + put) or put1 call with alias queue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you are using the `MQPMO_SYNCPOINT` option?  Are you also using the `MQPMO_SYNC_RESPONSE` option?  Please see the last note on the `MQPUT1` topic which states:

> When an MQPUT1 call is issued with MQPMO_SYNCPOINT, the default
>   behavior changes, so that the put operation is completed
>   asynchronously. This might cause a change in the behavior of some
>   applications that rely on certain fields in the MQOD and MQMD
>   structures being returned, but which now contain undefined values. An
>   application can specify MQPMO_SYNC_RESPONSE to ensure that the put
>   operation is performed synchronously and that all the appropriate
>   field values are completed.

In other words, the `PUT1` is handed off to WMQ and control returned to the program before the name resolution has occurred.

In any case, the `PUT1_BEFORE` exit point will not have resolved the name.  Assuming that `MQPMO_SYNC_RESPONSE` was specified, you should be able to find it in the `PUT1_AFTER` exit point.

If you install the API exit from [SupportPac MA0W](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMA0W), it parses all the control blocks and flags into English and formats a listing.  If you look at the output of that exit, you should be able to see exactly which exit points and fields contain the resolved names and when.

So, be sure to specify `MQPMO_SYNC_RESPONSE` and consider using the MA0W API exit as a reference and study aid.

Comment: Thanks Rob! MA0W traces made things much clearer. 
i had not specified any of the Put1 call options you mentioned, but my queue's default response type was set to synchronus, so i believe that must have been taken into account. You were right, PUT1_BEFORE exit never gives the resolved queue name (with or without MQPMO_SYNCPOINT option). Howeve in OPEN_AFTER exit i can see the resolved queue name (if mqod version = 3). So it's some what limiting to know that we can not find the target queue name when using put1 call. PUT1_AFTER exit however gives the resolved queue name as you mentoned.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the MQOD structure in the cmqc.h file.  The ResolvedQName field is ONLY available when the application used version 3 (or higher) of the MQOD structure.  If you check the version number of the MQOD, I bet you will see it is either version 1 or 2.

Note: The default version number for MQOD is 1. Hence, ResolvedQName field is not available.

Finally, the MQGMO and MQPMO structures both have the ResolvedQName field starting with version 1 of the structures.

Comment: Thanks Roger! Yuo are right with MQOD version 3, resolved queue name gets correctly set by queue manager (in OPEN_AFTER exit).  MQGMO and MQPMO also have the resolved queue name but they are set only in PUT_AFTER exits and not in PUT1_BEFORE exit.
       
Also the current .net MQ API uses version 1 of MQOD structure, and it seems there is no way to change the version!!